# Searchbox with filter in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question regarding this library https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search. I am trying to implement dropdown with searchbox, whenever I type in any value it doesn't show in the box and nothing is being returned in dropdown. How can I set this up properly?

[image]

```dart
            DropdownSearch(
                    mode: Mode.MENU,
                    dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF01689A)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    showAsSuffixIcons: true,
                    showClearButton: true,
                    items: _countryList.map((Country item) {
                      return item.label;
                    }).toList()
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of **searchDelay** field. When you make it 0 seconds it will work properly and become instant search.

```
   DropdownSearch<String>(
                        searchDelay: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                        showSearchBox: true,
                        showClearButton: true,
                          mode: Mode.MENU,
                          showSelectedItems: true,
                          items: transactionState.drop,
                          label: "Cari Hesap",
                          hint: "Cari Hesap Girin",
                          selectedItem: transactionState.selecteditem,
                          
                          //popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
                          onChanged: (str){
                            transactionState.getBakiye(str!);
                            transactionState.selecteditem = str;
    
                          },
                          ),
```